# LotusScript FTSearch on date fields

Tags: full-text-search, lotusscript, lotus

- I have a form with several Text fields and two Date fields, called - created and Deadline.
- I have full text search index on database

I'm trying to create dynamic search. So, on search form i added all fields, which i want to use in search and on Action search script generate query, which then used in FTSearch function. Everything works great with text fields, but with Date fields - something is going wrong. The result of search doesn't meet my expectations.

This is how my fields are represented in view:

```
created     Deadline    
08.10.2014  10.10.2014      
08.10.2014  14.10.2014      
06.10.2014  10.10.2014
```

Those are examples of my search query:

- "[created] >= 04.10.2014"
- "[created] >= 04.10.2014 & [created] <= 07.10.2014"
- "[created] >= 06.10.2014 & [Deadline] >= 08.10.2014"
- "[created] >= 03.10.2014 & [created] <= 05.10.2014 & [Deadline] >= 08.10.2014 & [Deadline] <= 11.10.2014"

But as i said - returned results have nothing similar with search query. What can be wrong?

Example: 
 - all documents

```
 Created        Deadline            
 09.10.2014 10.10.2014

 03.10.2014 09.10.2014

 08.10.2014 10.10.2014

 08.10.2014 14.10.2014

 07.10.2014 09.10.2014

 06.10.2014 10.10.2014

 06.10.2014 10.10.2014

 03.10.2014 06.10.2014
```

- query "[created] >= 07.10.2014"

result - all changes

- query "[created] >= 07.10.2014 & [created] <= 09.10.2014"

result - 0 documents

- "[Deadline] >= 09.10.2014"

  - result - all documents

This is how i call it and show in view:

```
    Set col = db.FTSearch(query, 0 )        
    Call col.putallinfolder("Search",True)
    Call ws.ViewRefresh
```

---

Can it be, that problem caused by fact, that fields created and Deadline store date without time?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the dates are stored as Date fields :
try replacing the period "." with a slash "/" in your date format. The FT search works on the date value rather than the textual representation.

eg

```
[created] >= 26/4/2014
```

Note the day and month numbers(I'm English) - you're at the mecry of the geographical setting of the server as to whether the format is dd-mm-yyyy (european) or mm-dd-yyyy (US format).

If the date are stored in text fields : 
Try quotes around the date values eg

```
[created] = "04.10.2014"
```

However comparison like >= (or >, < etc) won't work with a text field FT search. It only works on date and numeric fields.

Comment: I tried to change format - it doesn't help.
Also - dates are stored in Date/Time fields with the same format of representation for fields at the document form and at the search form.

Comment: Can you post an example of it not working ? ie what your query is, what the fields in the results are ? Is this running in the Notes Client search bar, or past of some lotusscript, or via web browser search URL ?

Comment: i added example to the first post

Comment: Ok I've just tried this on my email database via Notes cliend -   "[delivereddate] >= 7.10.2014 AND [delivereddate] <= 9.10.2014" (not in quotes)   -  seems to behave as expected. Perhaps your FT index needs to be deleted then re-created ? It doens't seem like you're doing anything wrong. Have you tried those queries directly in the Notes client ?

Comment: Yes. I tried them directly in the notes client. Have no idea why it doesn't work

Comment: I have tried this in my Notes mail client (directly in the search bar) using DeliveredDate field, but otherwise the same format as your queries.. It works as expected. You are right in that the . or / as the date format delimiter made no difference. So in that case I would suspect that your FT idex is corrupted. Have you tried deleting and then recreating the index ? My next suggestion would be the UNK table but I see from another post that you've already looked at that.

Comment: I have tried various ways with recreating indexes on new copy, on new replica - still the same

Answer (score 0):

It could be that when you first created the date field, you set it to text. Then you later changed the typ to date/time. 
That will have the field set to text in the UNK table, which would prevent you from doing these kind of searches. It is possible to rebuild the UNK table, but it can be tricky.
You can read more about the UNK table here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21100238

Comment: I know about UNK. I explored this topic deeply. I tried everything, related to UNK: deleting index, recreating, deleting with creation copy and replicas locally, then replicating again to server and recreating index. Field from the beginning where used like this: created is computed date/time field with value @Created and Deadline - editable date/time field with calendar style, where user chose proper date. So, that is why i am so confused about this.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view only problem is that you are trying to use internal Lotus Notes field/propery.

Just checked search with:

[_CreationDate]<07.10.2014 and [_CreationDate]<07/10/2014

Both work and return same valid result. I guess this is what you are looking for.

If you don't have real field named "created" on your form (and saved in values in your document of course) Then that formula will not return what you expect.

[_CreationDate] works almost as formula @created.

p.s. In deep Lotus Notes maze @created in some cases is not same as doc.created but thats different story.

Comment: I have field created with formula @created. But the problem is not only with created field, but with Deadline also.

Comment: Did you make sure that ftsearch works without your code. I mean does it work from view? Here is the sample screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/f0sX2of.png

Answer (score 0):

Okay, finally i found solution for this problem. So, FTSearch works as designed and query returns proper collection of documents. But the problem was with **putallinfolder** function, or, better to say - with response documents. Lotus clear search view every time, when in resulting collection there was document with child. So, i added custom function ptInFolder (i suppose, we can use also native putInFolder method of NotesDocument class):

```
Function putInFolder(doc As NotesDocument)
    On Error Goto catch
    Call doc.PutInFolder( "Search" )
catch:
    Exit Function
End Function
```

And on Search button click, i'm iterating through collection:

```
    Set col = db.FTSearch(query, 0 )    

    For i = 1 To col.Count

        Set doc = col.GetNthDocument( i )

        Call putInFolder(doc)           

    Next
```

Now everything works just fine. A little bit slowly, but the count of documents doesn't increase, so this solution is good for me.